# Is gulp-connect a suitable server for an AngularJs app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

Is gulp-connect a suitable server for an AngularJs app in a Production environment?  If not is their an alternative I can use with gulp and nodejs?

I've started learning AngularJs and am using gulp-connect in my dev environment and am wondering if it would be suitable for production.

Comment: Are you looking a solution for during the dev or prod?

Comment: express is pretty flushed out

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have a look on http://expressjs.com/ and http://restify.com/ also you can see bit of a comparison in the following article. http://techblog.netflix.com/search?q=node.js